# Kids find pirate treasure map

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember it's a group of 5 or 6 kids who find a map which indicates the position of a treasure, maybe related to a pirate chest.

- There was a fat boy who ate whipped cream at the beginning directly with the aerosol, or maybe it's mayonnaise.
- One has some glasses and he's smart. During a scene at the end he falls on a trap with spikes and gets out with a hand spring.
- One of riddles inside the movie is solved by a girl (or the main character, I'm not sure) by playing piano.

I watched this movie on TV several years ago, maybe in 2000. I think it's a US movie but I'm not really sure. It's not an animated movie.

Comment: First result when searching "Kids Find Treasure Map" is this question, then "The Goonies"
https://imgur.com/a/RWxNa

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Possibly [The Goonies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089218/) from 1985.

[Synopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goonies):

> The Goonies include optimist Mikey Walsh, his older brother, Brandon, the inventive Data, the talkative Mouth, and the overweight klutz Chunk. While rummaging through the Walshes' attic, they come across a 1632 doubloon and an old treasure map purporting to lead to the famous pirate "One-Eyed" Willy's hoard located nearby.

Girl playing an organ:

Escaping the trap:

Comment: I've had many an argument over "pinchers of peril" versus "pinchers of power" but I've never heard "pinchers from hell" before!